# question about `git rebase master` steps, github, and where the commits get moved to

Tags: git

I started a new job and they are much more into rebasing against master before making a pull request. I have used rebasing mostly for squash committing so I want to be sure I understand what is being asked of me and what it is doing.

Basically, my understanding is that they want you to:

1. make your changes on a 'feature' branch
2. commit
3. `git push` my feature branch
4. generate a pull request and get it reviewed / approved
5. Once approved, move to master `get checkout master` and `git pull` so that master is up to date.
6. move onto feature branch `git checkout feature` and  rebase locally against the master branch `git rebase master`. This will bring in all the changes from master and will recaulculate your sha1 hashes on feature's commits. Your commits will be placed on top of the last commit from master. This step doesn't change master branch in any way.
7. finally, force push up to your pull request as the commit sha1's are all different `git push -f'
8. merge into master the pull reqeust

This means that your pull request will be up to date with master and shouldn't conflict. Does this sound feasible / kinda standard? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could skip the go to master/pull/checkout feature-branch/rebase process and make it: `git fetch origin; git rebase origin/master` (assuming it's origin remote and master branch).

Comment: thx @eftshift0 that makes sense.  does everything else sound ok / consistent with best practices? I feel like sometimes I have seen that `git rebase master` replays the commits on 'top of master' seeming to imply that they are moved onto master at the point. However, that doesn't seem to be true - rather the commits on master not on my branch are moved over and the sha1's are recomputed. Obviously, don't want to do something that changes master.

Comment: You got it. And sure... rebase _recreates/reapplies_ the revisions you created on the feature branch on top of the current position of the branch you are using as your base... as if you had started development on the current tip of the branch (and the revisions are not related to the original revisions.... there's one option to hold the old ID but I don't think it's used that much and nothing keeps the old revisions from being GC if they are not linked)... but it can do a lot of other things. Rebase is very powerful, but that's one of the basic use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rebasing against master before making a pull request

Absolutely right. That is completely standard operating procedure.

Here's the idea. You make a branch and work on it.

```
A <- B <- C [master]
           \
            [branch]
```

Meanwhile `master` or `develop`, or wherever you guys always branch from and merge to, continues to advance. So your branch has now fallen behind.

```
A <- B <- C [master on your machine] <- D <- E [master at the remote]
           \
            J <- K [branch]
```

So now you finish your work and you are ready to merge. The way you do that, in your shared work flow, is with a push-plus-pull-request, so that others can inspect your work before the merge.

Okay, so just *before* the push-plus-pull-request, you quickly switch to `master` or `develop` or whatever it is, and `pull` to bring it up to date, and now switch back to your branch and `rebase` it on top of `master` or `develop` or whatever.

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E [master]
                     \
                      J´ <- K´ [branch]
```

If there are merge conflicts, fix them. Now push-and-pull-request.

That way, because of the `rebase`, your branch appears to emanate (and does in fact emanate) from the *end* of `master` or `develop` or whatever. This is good because:

- Unnecessary intervening commits are eliminated from the history.
- If there are any merge conflicts, they happen on your machine during the rebase, you take care of them, and there are no conflicts in the merge of the pull request.

So this makes for a very clean history and a very clean process.

Note that I have called the rebased J and K by slightly different names, J´ and K´. That's because when you rebase, your commits are rewritten. But that doesn't really matter. They will still have the same *effect* as the commits your originally created, and they will have the same commit messages as before. However, that is why, if you have *already* pushed your branch, you would now have to force push — basically any time you rewrite commits that have been pushed, you have to use force to push the rewritten commits. In my own practice, however, I do *not* push my branch at all until I'm completely finished and ready for the pull request.

(Personally, I also squash or rewrite the commit history on my branch before the push, too, so as to give the cleanest most helpfully organized history. But that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thanks! Love your books btw. Would it be possible to rebase multiple times? Or could problems be introduced by doing that?

Comment: It is absolutely possible and it is just what I do. All during the life of my branch, I keep doing what I just described: switch and pull, switch and rebase. That way, I am always as up to date as I can be. I do this often, like every couple of hours! Then I do it again one last time before the push. — One nice thing about that is, not only am I basing myself on the latest official code, but if there are conflicts I catch them and fix them early so there are fewer or none during that hurried last-minute final rebase.

Comment: The only thing I don't agree with in your flow is the force push. I don't push _at all_ until I'm done with my branch and ready for the push-and-pull-request. So there is no need for force, because there is no history to change. You only need force if you pushed, then rebased, then pushed again. That is a matter of opinion; there are people who do indeed force push as they go along. But I don't like that.